# FASM / emu8086 - Gerar executável 32bits/64bits

Tags: assembly

Olá, gostaria de saber como utilizar o FASM para gerar um executável .exe que rode em 32bits ou 64bits.

Acontece que ao gerar o .exe, ele não roda no Windows 7 por ser incompatível.

Eu utilizo o emu8086. Desde já, agradeço.

Print: http://prntscr.com/7g89qu

Comment: Sem ver o código é muito difícil ajudar.

Comment: Não tenho um código já pronto. Apenas desejo saber como faze-lo ser compatível com o S.O.

Esse é o código "padrão" quando clico para fazer um novo projeto .exe
http://pastebin.com/59b1hCD3

Comment: Cara, eu não vou nem arriscar a responder esta pergunta pq realmente não sei. Agora eu encontrei algo que pode te ajudar: https://jakash3.wordpress.com/2010/07/23/fasm-tutorial-16-32-bit/

Comment: Muito obrigado Edgar. O link me informou exatamente o que eu precisava saber. :D

Muito obrigado mesmo.